# Neatly displaying an output from the command prompt in PHP

Tags: python, php, command-prompt

I wish to neatly display the output of a python file after it has run some commands in the command prompt.

Currently, a part of my PHP code looks like this:

```
$output2 = shell_exec('python amassprocess.py 2>&1' . $asnum);
echo $output2
```

It basically sends the user input to the python file amassprocess.py and runs the file with the user input.

The amassprocess.py file looks like this currently:

```
import os, sys

#asnum = sys.argv[1]
asnum = "46489"

print("Here is a list of top level seed domain related to the AS Number provided:")
topdomain = os.system('cmd /c "amass.exe intel -asn {}"'.format(asnum))
for i in topdomain:
    print(i)
    print("<br>")
```

PS: ignore the 2 asnum, one of them is for testing

The resulting output from running the python script is this:

```
Here is a list of top level seed domain related to the AS Number provided:
ttvnw.net
justin.tv
twitch.tv
socialcam.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:/xampp/htdocs/majorproject/amassprocess.py", line 8, in <module>
    for i in topdomain:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

However, what i hope the output to be when i run the python script is as follows:

```
Here is a list of top level seed domain related to the AS Number provided:
ttvnw.net
<br>
justin.tv
<br>
twitch.tv
<br>
socialcam.com
```

This so that when it is displayed in PHP, it looks like this:

```
Here is a list of top level seed domain related to the AS Number provided:
ttvnw.net
justin.tv
twitch.tv
socialcam.com
```

Currently in PHP, the result are all just displayed in a single line like so:

```
ttvnw.net justin.tv twitch.tv twitchcon.com socialcam.com Traceback (most recent call last): File "amassprocess.py", line 7, in for i in topdomain: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I would be grateful for any help or ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code, you can replace newlines with `<br />`:

```
$output2 = shell_exec('python amassprocess.py 2>&1' . $asnum);
echo nl2br($output2);
```

Or you can get an array of lines and join on `<br />`::

```
exec('python amassprocess.py 2>&1' . $asnum, $output2);
echo implode('<br />', $output2);
```

Alternately, with your code, you can display in `<pre>` or maybe `<code>` tags, which browsers will render pre-formatted with newlines, tabs etc:

```
$output2 = shell_exec('python amassprocess.py 2>&1' . $asnum);
echo "<pre>$output2</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks man. It works like a charm. Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following in your python code.

1. define one variable to hold 
    like `x="<br>"`
2. and then use for output `print(i+x)` this will concatenate your string.

Comment: Hi so if i understand you correctly, is this what you are referring to?



x="<br>"

topdomain = os.system('cmd /c "amass.exe intel -asn {}"'.format(asnum))
for i in topdomain:
    print(i+x)

I've tried it like this but it still doesn't work and produced the same error.